# ¿Cómo saber qué clave primaria ó alternativa usa una consulta cuando accede a X tabla?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Pues esa es la pregunta. Si tengo una consulta que selecciona datos de una tabla, ¿cómo puedo saber la clave por la que la consulta accede a esa tabla?

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT CLIENT,TITLE,SEASON, COUNT('X') N_EPISODIOS FROM LIC_SERIES 
GROUP BY CLIENT,TITLE,SEASON;
```

Y la tabla LIC_SERIES es:

```
CREATE TABLE lic_series(
client VARCHAR2(15), 
datetime DATE,
title VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL, 
season  NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
episode NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_licsS PRIMARY KEY (client,title,season,episode),
CONSTRAINT FK_licsS1 FOREIGN KEY (title,season) REFERENCES seasons);
```

¿Por qué clave accede la consulta a la tabla licencias? Primaria, alternativa?
¿Por qué?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usa explain plain

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm

( supongo que es para Oracle )

Esto es relleno para que pueda mandar el comentario, porque me exige que no sea demasiado corto....

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo a que te refieres por clave, pero una tabla se accesa directo (full table scan - FTS) o a través de un indice. Dependiendo del tamaño de esta tabla, oracle decidirá si es mas barato hacer un full table scan, o hacer la consulta por el indice.

Ahora bien, dado que no tienes ninguna condición en tu SELECT, esta consulta hará un full table scan, no importa cuantos indices le pongas, sin el WHERE la única opción es un FTS.

Saludos

AC